# Minitoc won't work at my Report document

Tags: minitoc

I am about 3 days deep into this whole minitoc issue. 
WHY doesn't it work?

I mean, I want a simple mini table of contents at the beginning of each chapter in my report document.

Let me show you some example of code.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{ragged2e} 
\usepackage{minitoc} 
\usepackage{sectsty}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[table,dvipsname]{xcolor}% http://ctan.org/pkg/xcolor
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}

%%%%%%%% FOR TESTING %%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%Initializing Minitoc
\dominitoc[n]
\nomtcpagenumbers

\begin{document}




    \chapter{A}
    \label{Chap.A}

        \minitoc % GENERATE THE MINITOC?

        \section{A.1}
        \label{A:sec:1}

        Minitoc, what is wrong with you please tell me!

        \section{A.2}
        \label{A:sec:2}
        \blindtext

    \newpage

    \chapter{B}
    \label{Chap.B}

        \minitoc % ????

        \section{B.1}
        \label{B:sec:1}
        \Blindtext

        \section{B.2}
        \label{B:sec:2}
        \blindtext

\end{document}
```

When I compile this, I get

[image]

Obviously I am doing something wrong. What is it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The package makes a very clear warnings in the log that it can not work without `\tableofcontents`

```
Package minitoc Warning: W0010
(minitoc)                No file bb599.toc. 
(minitoc)                MINITOCS NOT PREPARED on input line 17.
```

and

```
Package minitoc(hints) Warning: W0068
(minitoc(hints))                You have used \minitoc but not 
(minitoc(hints))                \tableofcontents
(minitoc(hints))                nor \faketableofcontents.
```

if you add `\tableofcontents` after `\begin{document}` you get

[image]

There are other warnings, about package ordering that I have not addressed here, for example

```
Package minitoc(hints) Warning: W0037
(minitoc(hints))                The sectsty package should be 
(minitoc(hints))                loaded BEFORE the minitoc package.
```

Comment: Alright. Thank you very much. I didn't notice any warnings during the build. Only that the process exited normally. I have one more question if possible. Is there a way in this specific document example for the "Chapter X" field to appear in the left side of the page and the A (chapter name) to appear ti the right  for each chapter ?

Comment: @Broxigar always check the log file.

Comment: Alright. Good to know. As far as the text manipulation ? Is there a way?

Comment: @Broxigar that;s a different question but sure the chapter heading  layout is only a few lines of report class so you could copy and redefine as needed or since you are loading secsty  you could specify the heading layout using the commands of that package